# how handle error in http.Get in function

Tags: go

I have a problem whith this function:

```
func execute(query Query) (goreq.Response, error) {

    res, err := goreq.Request{
        Uri:         "http://path/to/host",
        QueryString: query,
        Accept:      "application/json",
        UserAgent:   "XXXGoClient/1.0",
        Timeout:     2000 * time.Millisecond,
        Compression: goreq.Gzip(),
        //ShowDebug:   true,
    }.Do()

    return *res, err
}
```

i am getting `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` when a error in http request ocurrs.

I know that i would check for something like this:

```
if err != nil {
    // do somthing here
}
```

but i dont know what i must to do, for example this:

```
if err != nil {
    return
}
```

i get `./main.go:113: not enough arguments to return`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not used to http requests in go, but I guess the error comes from '*res' as 'res' is nil when there's an error.

What I'd do is to return a pointer (*goreq.Response), avoiding the dereference:

```
func execute(query Query) (*goreq.Response, error) {
    return goreq.Request{
       // original code goes here
    }.Do()
}
```

In that case you will dereference the pointer where the value of the response is needed and can be ignored if the error is not nil.

Hope it helps.

Comment: if i do this get `main.go:113: cannot use nil as type goreq.Response in return argument `

Comment: In that case what I would do is to return a pointer (*goreq.Response) so you can return nil in the case that the response from the .Do() function is nil, and dereference the pointer where the response is actually needed.

I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

finally i resolve this as follow

```
if err != nil {
    var empty goreq.Response
    return empty, err
}
```

Comment: While this solution works as well, the solution proposed by Gerard Abello has the following advantages: there is less code and the returned goreq.Response object is not copied via stack (fairly fast operation but not exactly free especially for big structs)

Answer (score -1):

From my limited experience, errors are values. Your function returns two values, `return`, ain't enough. How about `return nil, nil` if there is no response to return anyway...
Or you can bring it down with `panic(err)`. Depends on what you want to do if the request fails.

Comment: I would not return nil as the error, because in go that means there was no error and that's not the case.

Comment: Well, yes, that is a semantic question of error handling -- the issue on hand is about the number of return values though...